# Reset button not working in the form after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a php page 'search.php'. One form in the page. I have one submit and one reset button. The reset button works before the form is submit but it doesn't work after the submit. The page is redirected to the same page (search.php) after form submission to view the results which contains the same form. Does anyone have a clue on this problem?

```
    <form action="http://localhost:8888/search/validate_search" name="search" id="search" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <p>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" required="required">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="country">Country</label>

        <select name="country[]" id="country">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan" >Afghanistan</option><option 

value="Albania" >Albania</option><option value="Algeria" >Algeria</option><option value="American Samoa" >American Samoa</option><option value="Andorra" >Andorra</option><option value="Angola" >Angola</option><option value="Anguilla" >Anguilla</option>            </select>

    </p>
    <p id="nofloat">
        <input type="submit" name="searchButton" value="Search" id="searchButton"  />
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" id="reset123"/>
    </p>
   </form>
```

Comment: Show us the code please.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The behavior of `type='reset'` is not to clear the form elements, but to return them to the initial/default values *when the page was loaded*. After you submit your form, if you are then passing the submitted values back to the form to be pre-populated (set as the initial values) of the form, then your reset button will only reset the fields to those passed values, not to a "clean" state. To actually clear the form, you will need to use Javascript.

Here is an example that would work for the HTML given in your question...

```
<script>
function customReset()
{
    document.getElementById("name").value = "";
    document.getElementById("country").value = "";
}
</script>
```

Just change your reset button to this...

```
<input type="button" name="reset" value="Reset" id="reset123" onclick="customReset();"/>
```

[Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/3bhjos50/)

Comment: I used the javascript .reset() function but it returns an error.
.reset() is not a function error.

Comment: @ManikShakya That's because you have an element named "reset". That will override the native Javascript `reset()` function. But you don't want to use that function since it does the same thing as the `type='submit'` input field.  You need to write code to explicitly set the fields to blank values.  See the update.

Comment: @ManikShakya If that solved your problem, then you should mark this answer as accepted so that people know.

Comment: Please note that : using `type="button"` is better than using `type="reset"` because there will be a conflict btween HTML reset and JS reset.